# Enable-ADAccount script occasionally fails due to password complexity

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords, elevated-privileges

I'm trying to add all the AD users that have a samaccountname ending in some suffix to a few different AD groups. This code works for all of the users with the suffic except for one.

When trying to enable that user, it throws

`The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.`

The password for the user **does** meet the requirements (8+chars, numbers, capitals, special chars).

The account was created 2 days ago. Yesterday the automation that was running the script failed, however this morning when I ran the script manually the user was enabled.

Why would Enable-ADAccount fail, and then suddenly pass? Is it possible that AD was complaining about the account trying to enable the AD account? If so, why only complain about a single account? Is it possible the account must exist for 2 days before the account can be enabled?

```
[string]$suffix = "<my-suffix>"
[string[]]$AdmingGroups = @("group1","group2")
[psobject[]]$AdminUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * | ? { $_.samaccountname -match $suffix} | Select SamAccountName

foreach ($User in $AdminUsers) {
    [string]$SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName
    try {
        foreach ($ADGroup in $AdminGroups) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Members $SamAccountName
        }
        Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $SamAccountName
        # This fails
        Enable-ADAccount -Identity $SamAccountName
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to escalate AD Account $SamAccountName"
        # Print out the exception
        Write-Host $_
    }
}
```

Comment: once the account is created you can enable/disable it. in regards to pwd complexity note that the password may not contain the samaccountname or parts of the displayname:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements

Comment: The password doesn't include the samaccountname, and the displayname is blank

Comment: Did the account have a password when the script was first run? You can create a disabled account without a password, but to enable it, it needs to have a password first (unless it has the flag to specify that it doesn't need a password). Check the `pwdLastSet` attribute: `Get-ADUser -Identity username -Properties pwdLastSet`

Comment: Yes, the password was set a few days ago

Comment: Please show us how you created that user and especially handled the accountpassword for it